# Adsense RPM dropped more than 70%

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

My RPM (Revenue Per Thousand views) on AdSense started to drop for past couple weeks, and now its 72,6% less than 28 days ago.

Only things that I can think of that I did in past 28 days:

I moved one of the pages to httpS (but my other site has SSL enabled for months and I never had that problem) and also i think RPM should not be affected by that, only the actual income.

And then I added one more ad to one of sites. All of the sites have maximum of 1 ad per page (as I hate when people use tons of ads). and I noticed the drops of RPM right after I enabled it. Also, like 25-50% of the time, it just shows blank space (so AdSense has no ads for me), but that too should not affect RPM.

Does somebody have any idea? All google tips are at 5 or at least 4 out of 5 points/dots, so there is no problem either.

If the drop was like 20%, I would be somewhat ok, but 72,6% drop and still dropping? For past 28 days I had 246 275 views of my pages.

Is there some fix I can do, is it some google bug or thats just how google works? Will it get back up? As I have to pay for servers, and even before drop it was bad (thats why I had to ad that one more ad to site), now its just terrible and I am getting less money with that new ad, than i was getting without it.

Thanks.

Here is screen of my Adsense Performance reports:
[image: Adsense Performance Report]

Here is report of Ad Sizes:
[image: AdSense AdSizes report]

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have made the required changes to the adsense code for SSL compliance. Read this - https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10528?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438

> Also, like 25-50% of the time, it just shows blank space (so AdSense has no ads for me), but that too should not affect PPT.

Adsense fill rate generally remain over 90% for almost all verticals so if you are experiencing 25-50% no-fills, then there is definitely a big problem. It will also impact RPM (Revenue per '1000 pageviews) if that's what you mean by PPT and total income as well.

Fix SSL thing and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: All of my ads start with //, they did even before I forced SSL on my pages. Also, the vertical ads are always filled, but I use them only on one section of site, other pages have horizontal 728x90px ads. And yes I mean RPM, in my adsense language its called PTZ, so I just tried to somehow translate it, so you would understand what I actually mean. I tried http://ctrlq.org/sandbox and that show only some of the ads, others have blank spaces third of the time.

Comment: In that case, you need to provide more information - 
1. RPM basically depends on CTR (click through rate) and CPC (cost per click)? What is the fall in each of them?
2. What is the impact on your earnings?
3. Your sites are targeting which country. Depreciation of local currency can also impact earnings in USD because advertisers will keep on paying in local currency. e.g. russia's rouble has lost majorly against USD in recent times.

Comment: I added screen od my Performance report to my question. Ts a report for multiple sites I have, so it does not look so drastic, but the site where it hit me the most is generatirn 52% less money than it was before. Also site is aimed at everybody. Its in English language, but I have users from all over the globe. Right now I have 10% less total income, but thats only cos my 2 other pages are somehow keeping their revenue pretty good. My RPM was 0,62€ 28 days ago now its 0,17€.

Comment: As I have told earlier RPM depends CPC and CTR. From the graph, I can see - 
1. Significant drop in the CTR
2. CPC has infact improved

So, your problem is very low CTR (Click Through Rate). See, if you have positioned your ad correctly? check whether adsense able to crawl your pages. You can also go to adsense ad unit report and see which ads have minimum CTR. Read more on declining CTR here [link](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/160523?hl=en)

Comment: Well, the ads never changed their positions, only thing changed about ads is, that I added one more ad to pages where I had no ads before. And crawler can crawl the site normally, its not blocked or anything like that. I also checked my ads, and they all fluctuate, but not by that much... So I have no idea. I actually checked the ad sizes, and the 728x90 have a big drop in Ad Request CTR. I am adding screen to my question in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Did you receive this message in your AdSense account in April month "Your site's mobile-friendliness is now considered as a Google Search ranking signal."

After applying this changes all adsense users getting lower RPM. Maybe your website is not mobile friendly.

Comment: Yep I did and nope, its not mobile friendly and its not even supposed to be, there is actually no way you could make it mobile friendly. All sites that can be mobile friendly are done such way (responsive or either separate mobile page). But funny is, the RPM al all of that happened right after I added one more add to all of my pages (to list of videos). So I dont think the mobile friendliness is the problem. After I added it my page views wen rapidly up and right after that they went instantly down and are not comming back up.